# why in the API Demo's AlarmService_Service.java, it says"just sleep for 30 seconds" instead of 15 seconds?

Tags: android, api, alarm, demo

I just looked through the AlarmService sample in the Android API Demo(API 8).

When the AlarmManager in the AlarmService.java file use setRepeating() method to schedule the alarm, the service will create a new thread in the AlarmService_Service.java file.

My question is:

In the run() method of the mTask Runnable object, why it says "we will just sleep for 30 seconds."? My understanding is: the thread starts, and it waits/sleeps for 15 seconds(NOT 30 seconds), then this thread will be stop by calling the stopSelf() method. So it will sleep 15 seconds instead of 30, right? Am I missing something?

Any Hints?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService_Service.html

Comment: also this one:http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Alarm

Comment: Sometimes comments are wrong.

Comment: I have very little Android Development experience, but it looks to me like it was just a typo on the author's part.

Comment: You guys are right. I just read the other Alarm example, they set the alarm go off every 15 seconds, but they commented "go off every 30 seconds". Codes do not lie :-) THX

Comment: In that case, added as an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

People make mistakes. Despite my little experience with Android Development, it seems like it is a mistake.

Of course, the real way to find out is to use a stopwatch while running the code.